# How to get Cloud Front Distribution IP?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-cloudfront

I need to make trust all cloudfront ip addresses in .Net Core Application in ForwardedHeadersOptions to get the Real Client IP Address but not getting that. Using below code  to setup ForwardedHeadersOptions in Startup.cs

```
        services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
            options.KnownNetworks.Add(new IPNetwork(IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xx.x.x"), 12));
        });
```

Please let me know, How can get all IPs for cloud front?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon CloudFront has *many* IP ranges associated with it. Therefore, things might be more complex than you conceive.

You can obtain the IP address ranges of *all* AWS services at: [AWS IP address ranges - AWS General Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html)

Comment: Thanks to reply. I also found http://d7uri8nf7uskq.cloudfront.net/tools/list-cloudfront-ips to get only cloud front ips. I have a concern, can this url change or remain same? I am asking because, want to use this url to load these ips and use.

Comment: I did a web search and couldn't find any official AWS Documentation referring to that URL, so I don't know whether that is an official listing.

Comment: here is AWS page that contains that url https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LocationsOfEdgeServers.html

Comment: Ah! In that case, yes, you could rely on that being updated.

Comment: @Ravi, yes I think that the anycast IP of your CloudFront may change. If you want a fixed one, you should use AWS Global Accelerator.